# check all checkbox bug after clicking first child

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("#main").click(function(e) {

  $('.child').prop('checked', !$('.child').prop("checked"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="main" type="checkbox">
<br>
<br>
<input class="child" type="checkbox">
<br>
<input class="child" type="checkbox">
<br>
<input class="child" type="checkbox">
<br>
<input class="child" type="checkbox">
<br>
```

I have problem doing a check all function. When I click on #main, everything is fine even the toggling works. But try to click on the first child first and then click on the #main, I experience a strange behavior there. It doesn't happen to 2,3 or 4th child checkbox, why is it so?

Answer (score 3):

Use `$(this)` instread of `$('.child')`.

Or use `$('.child').prop('checked', this.checked);` suggested by @Balachandran:-

```js
$("#main").click(function(e){       
    $('.child').prop('checked',$(this).prop("checked"));
});

$(".child").change(function(e){     
   if($('.child:checked').length== $('.child').length){
        $('#main').prop('checked',true);
   } else{
     $('#main').prop('checked',false);
   }

//or more short you can use
 $('#main').prop('checked',$('.child:checked').length== $('.child').length);
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="main" type="checkbox">
<br><br>
<input class="child" type="checkbox">
    <br>
<input class="child" type="checkbox"><br>
<input class="child" type="checkbox"><br>
<input class="child" type="checkbox"><br>
```

Comment: when i uncheck the second checkbox the main check box(i.e. ALL)   is not unchecking ...

Comment: sorry im not the original OP